# Meaning of 'Nothing herein shall require the Owner to disclose any of its information' in an agreement document?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, legalese, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the sentence from an agreement document?

> Nothing herein shall require the Owner to disclose any of its information.

The sentence previous to this sentence has some types of confidential information that the owner (client) will disclose to the recipient (company).

Comment: What part of this sentence is causing difficulty? As in - these words all have meanings that you may know already, or can find in a dictionary; in what way does putting those together not produce a meaning that fits the context?

Comment: Does it mean 'nothing in the document shall require owner's permission to disclose any information'? @psmears?

Comment: No - it means the Owner is not required to disclose any of its information, and can keep it undisclosed despite anything else in the document.  It may be that *its* is a key word here. Consult a lawyer if this is important.

Comment: It should be noted that this is "legal language", also known as "legalese". You're probably best off asking a lawyer (solicitor, if you're speaking Commonwealth English) to translate this into words of one syllable.

Comment: "herein" refers to the document containing the cited text. All it means is that *the document itself* contains nothing that would compel "the Owner" to tell anyone else about *anything* in the document. But presumably owner can *choose* to disclose details - or feasibly the law (or some other "persuasive force") might *require* disclosure, even if the document itself doesn't.

Comment: Why something would compel 'the Owner' to tell anyone about anything in the document? Should the word 'the Owner' be replaced with 'the Recipient'? @FumbleFingers?

Comment: @Shem15: One would expect "the Owner" (capital O) to have been defined elsewhere in the document (perhaps "A.N. Other, the sole proprietor of Acme Enterprises Ltd, hereinafter referred to as the Owner").

Comment: @Shem15: Presumably you know the full context, but I don't. I'm just assuming it's something like a surveyor's report on a property that's up for sale. In which case it's probably useful for the surveyor to tell ***the owner of the property*** (if he commissioned the survey) that he's not under any legal obligation to show that survey to any potential buyers. 15-20 years ago the UK govt. toyed with the idea of making house sellers pay for a survey that they would then have to show to potential buyers, in an attempt to reduce overall costs. But it was a daft Idea, so it was quickly dropped.